# What is the error in this merge sort implementation?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, mergesort

```
def merge(l1,l2):

  (lmerged,i,j) = ([],0,0)

  while i+j < len(l1) + len(l2):
    if i == len(l1):
      lmerged.append(l2[j])
      j = j+1
    elif j == len(l2):
      lmerged.append(l1[i])
      i = i+1
    elif l1[i] < l2[j]:
      lmerged.append(l1[i])
      i = i+1
    elif l2[j] < l1[i]:
      lmerged.append(l2[j])
      j = j+1
    else:
      lmerged.append(l1[i])
      i = i+1
      j = j+1

  return(lmerged)    

def mergesort(l):
  if len(l) < 2:
    return(l)
  else:
    n = len(l)
    leftsorted = mergesort(l[:n//2])
    rightsorted = mergesort(l[n//2:])
    return(merge(leftsorted,rightsorted))
```

What is the error in this code sample? On which list will this implementation fail? Is the logic correct or there is some flaw in my logic itself?

Comment: What's with the hypothetical questions? On which list **did** it fail? What error **did** it give? Have you actually had any error with it?

Comment: My teacher said it is failing a test list and he isn't telling me the list. Now I have ran my mind wild trying to figure out where it will fail.

Comment: Then your teacher is not teaching you. without the error and list to test how does he expect you to modify the code to work as he expects it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**fail test**: `[1, 1]` is sorted as `[1]`

**fix**: remove `j = j + 1` in `merge` function in the last `else` block.

Comment: Thanks Can you please tell where this perfect number finder function is failing too please

Comment: def perfect(n):
    if n==1 or n==0:
      return True
    elif n<0:
      return False    
    sum = 0
    for x in range(1, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            sum += x
    return sum == n